# Debug adapter protocol - confused

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I am creating C# Avalonia application with scripting capabilities using `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting`.

Scripting is done inside the application. I would like to have the ability to do limited debugging inside the app as well - without IDE.

By searching online I found that C# debugging is hard outside of Visual Studio or Rider.

I found this library [Microsoft.Samples.Debugging](https://github.com/SymbolSource/Microsoft.Samples.Debugging), is very old and probably won't work on modern .NET versions anymore.

I can probably use [Debug Adapter Protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/specification). DAP on its web explain basic protocol, but the specification is missing how this exchange actually happens. I want to make my own DAP Client, and use already made debug adapter for C#.

[Here](https://github.com/OmniSharp/csharp-language-server-protocol) is implementation of dap clinet/server and `System.IO.Pipelines` is used for communication, is that a standard?

Searching more, I found that vim and emacs dap implementation are using [netcoredbg](https://github.com/Samsung/netcoredbg), and not VS Code implementation, for some reason. That is CLI based and not JSON msg based, so I am very confused. Netcoredbg is not even listed on DAP site.

I am expecting that debug adapters are not build specifically for one IDE, so they can be consumed in any DAP clinet.

I don't know if debug adapter is a separate executable (netcoredb), or a library. And how these two are communicating - pipelines? http?

Can someone please clear my confusion?

Comment: You have a http connection with a client and server.  The client and server are two different applications.  You need to have a separate debugger on both client and server to simultaneously debug.  Or you can create a debug logger on the server to save the error message to a log file.  You could also return the error messages in the response when server fails.  For testing purposes you could make two different project (one for client and one for server) so you can debug.  Later you could combine the client and server code.  The server would need to be started before the client.

Comment: @jdweng Sorry if i was confusing. Client means the IDE and server is the debug adapter. I am asking about Debug Adapter Protocol, not about general client<-> server communciation.

Comment: Try remote debugging : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2022

Comment: @jdweng like a explaned, I am debugging localy. And I know how to debug using vscode, visual studio or rider. But I want to have debuging capabilites inside my own application, propably using DAP. I dont want to use visual studio. vscode, or rider.

Comment: Your link says following "The Debug Adapter Protocol defines the protocol used between an editor or IDE and a debugger or runtime."  A protocol is a connection between a client and server.  The protocol defines the communication language.  It is a specification.  Do you really need to know how the Protocol is implemented?  It could be in one or many libraries.  Or even built into the code.  Do you care if the connection is over ethernet, an internal tunnel in the operating system, or a pipe.

Comment: @jdweng I need to know how to speak with the implenetation, because if i dont know what ip address, port, or pipe name it is, I have no way of exchanging any messages explaned in the specification.

Comment: Lets get back to basic 7 Layers of Networking.  DAP is the data layer.  The data can be sent over any Transport Layer.  If you are implementing both ends of the Transport Layer you simply put the DAP layer onto your transport layer.

Answer (score 0):

Debug adapter can be a completely separate process.
Method of communication between IDE and debug adapter is not standardised.

Because of that, debug adapters using DAP doesn't have to be compatible with IDE using DAP.

VS Code is using socket on a specific port or stdin/stdout. OmniSharp.Extensions.DebugAdapter is using pipelines.